# how to start only one 3dsmax instance pertime

Tags: instance, 3dsmax

Whenever a command like "3dsmax -silent -U PythonHost F:/code/3dmax/dsmax_snapshot.py" is executed, a new instance is started。I want to execute the script using only the opened instance each time

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to call `registerOLEInterface` to expose `python.ExecuteFile` (and/or `python.Execute`) from the script you pass on the commandline, then you can use [win32com to execute python commands](https://forums.cgsociety.org/t/python-mxs/1066622) in that running max instance. For this to work, you have to first [register the OLE server](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_D454F1B5_30FE_4485_8A02_ABE79129807C_htm). Once the keys are added to the registry, you can expose the needed functions and call them from outside of max.